# DSP grpc.dsp Does not Exist PHP

Tags: php, dll, composer-php

[image]

Hi collegues, unfortunately I've been fighting with this issue, I don't know what to do. I'n trying to install through pecl on windows but for some reason it does not work, every time i put the install command it ends up saying DSP grpc.dsp does not exist, even when I typed pecl install grpc-beta.

I appreciate if some of you may help me out!

Thanks!

I'm trying to install the grpc extension on PHP because I want to use a dependence in composer which is requesting it.

Comment: What is "this issue"? How is your problem related to Composer?

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. There's far from enough info to tell what's going on, both what you did and in what order and also what happen in response to that.